# Why does Debian prefer a temp file replacing the original over modifying bytes in original file?

Tags: debian, files, filesystems, tmp, write

In the `mp3gain` manpages, you can read the following:

```
   -t        mp3gain  writes  modified  mp3  to  temp  file,  then deletes
             original instead of modifying bytes in original file (This is
             the default in Debian)

   -T        mp3gain modifies bytes in original file instead of writing to
             temp file.
```

Most distros (and Windows for that matter) change some bytes (if possible in padded tag space of mp3's I guess). This has the added benefit of being faster. Especially when tagging thousands of files. This also has the added benefit of only syncing the changed cluster to e.g. Dropbox.

Debian, however, rewrites the entire file, including the changed bytes, to a temporary file, after which the original file is replaced with the temporary file.

I would like to know why exactly this is. I would like to know the actual reason(s) from someone who knows this for a fact. (You are free to make an educated guess, but I might hold off accepting your answer until I get more.)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what does this have to do with Debian? It is what `mp3again` does. `mp3again` is a program; it is not "Debian".

Comment: The man page suggests that the `-t` option is the default for Debian - hence the OP's question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question suggests that Debian uses temp files for all writes, which isn't the case.  This is simply the default for `mp3gain`.

In version 1.4.3-2, the package maintainer (Stefan Fritsch) decided that as writing to a temp file is much quicker on ReiserFS, then this would be the default on Debian. This was sourced from the [patch](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mp3gain/mp3gain_1.5.1-4.diff.gz) at https://packages.debian.org/source/squeeze/mp3gain

Package maintainers on other distros presumably didn't agree with Stefan and therefore didn't change the default of not using temp files.

Comment: You are correct: `Make -t the default since it is faster on ReiserFS.` Good one. But irrelevant to the quality of your answer, I find slowing down `Ext4` to benefit `ReiserFS` a bit odd: _"Reiser4 has a somewhat uncertain future. It has not yet been accepted into the main line Linux kernel, the lead designer is in prison, and the company developing it is not currently in business. (...) it may not be a good choice for long term use."_ https://www.serverfocus.org/reiserfs-vs-ext4-vs-xfs-vs-zfs-vs-btrfs

Comment: I agree. That was in 2004 though, which could have been the height of ResierFS popularity. That could, in some eyes, make it important at the time.  You could raise a bug against the package as no other distro seems to set this as default and as you say ReiserFS isn't that popular these days.

Comment: @Redsandro `-t` has another, more important advantage: [safety](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165772).

Comment: @Gilles that's debatable. Mp3 tags have padding, invented _specifically_ to allow in-file updating of tags. Worst that can happen is an incomplete or corrupt tag. Corrupt tags are ignored and the mp3 audio stream is fine as ever. You don't need to wear a seat belt when you're on the couch watching a movie.

Answer (score 2):

You should *never* ever modify a file in place. The only safe ways to write a file are:

1. if you are the first one to create the file (`O_EXCL`).
2. by writing to a new temporary file and then performing an (atomic) `rename(2)`.
3. by opening the file in append-only mode (`O_APPEND`).

Otherwise, you *will* lose data all the time, either when your program crashes (don't lie and say your program is perfect) or when you lose power.

There are plenty of major applications that haven't learned these rules yet; I blame the fact that there even *is* an option to open a file in write-truncate mode (since there is no use at all for it).

Comment: You are saying the one proper reason is to prevent data loss? Isn't that what a _journaling_ file system is for? (Also, (laptops and) offices have `UPS`ses.) (Upvoted.)

Comment: @Redsandro This has nothing to do with journaling. Journaling doesn't even prevent data loss, per se; what it does is to make crash recovery faster. No filesystem-level feature can prevent the file from being inconsistent if the application writing it crashes midway. There has to be an application-level change, of which writing to a new file and then moving the new file in place is by far the easiest to carry out.

Answer (score 1):

Changing a file in place is not always that easy.

If you add date in the middle of a file, the size will grow and any data after the change has to be written to a new location. If you first write the data in the middle of the file, you have to store the old data in order to move it, and hope not to crash in the middle of that process.
It is much easier to simply write the result into a new file.

Writing to a new file (and afterwards replacing it the original file) has also the advantage that any process accessing the old file will be able to continue its work undisturbed. If you move things around in that file such a process might get confused quite a bit.

Comment: Upvoted because of the _"process accessing the old file"_ idea. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Somewhat related, the "memfd seal" kernel patches can *ensure* that nobody can write to a file later.